# syslinux / vesamenu.c32 - using highest available screen resolution?

Tags: boot-loader, resolution, syslinux

I was wondering if there was a way to use the highest available resolution in the syslinux.cfg file?

I know i can do:

```
MENU RESOLUTION 1024 768
```

but without knowing available resolutions beforehand, is there a way to just choose the highest and have multiple backgrounds for different sizes etc?

Comment: Thanks! Your question answered my question :-) I just wanted to know how to set the resolution in the first place.